# Creating a non-admin user in Rundeck

Tags: rundeck

I am having trouble creating a non-admin user.

I have been able to create users and add the desired roles for them in the `realm.properties` file.

My problem is that every user I create is given the admin role, in addition to the other roles I specify.

My user creation process goes like this:

1. useradd myuser
2. passwd myuser
3. edit realm.properties to add the line `myuser:mypassword,user,group2,group3`

I have also added a user first in the realm.properties before adding the user to the system to see if it made a difference. It did not.

I know I fundamentally don't understand how Rundeck is authenticating users, but the fact that everything works, except that the user always has the role of admin in addition to the other desired roles, is driving me nuts.

EDIT:

Adding description of other attempt at user creation

1. Create `operationsuser2` user in `realm.properties`
2. Restart rundeck (or the machine running rundeck)
3. Fail to log in as user `operationsuser2`

Adding my `realm.properties`

```
#
# This sets the default user accounts for the Rundeck app
#
admin:admin,user,admin,architect,deploy,build
otheradmin:adminPass,user,admin,architect,deploy,build
operationsuser1:myPass1,user,operations
operationsuser2:myPass2,user,operations
```

Adding the Access Policy that I have been trying to test this whole time lol

```yaml
description: Operations manager project access
context:
  application: 'rundeck'
by:
  group: operations
for:
  project:
    - equals:
        name: 'myProject'
      allow: [read]

---
description: Operations manager project specific rules
context:
  project: 'myProject'
by:
  group: operations
for:
  job:
    - equals:
        uuid: 096852ba-099e-42c1-9373-11621f17398d
      allow: [read, run]
  node:
    - allow: 'read'
  adhoc:
    - allow: [read, run]
```

I think I have found out why all the users are admins. After clearing up some miscommunication with my coworker who originally set up Rundeck, he told me that he set up PAM, which led me to investigate the jaas config below.
We are using the JettyPamLoginModule.

➜  ~ sudo cat /etc/rundeck/jaas-loginmodule.conf

```java
RDpropertyfilelogin {
  org.rundeck.jaas.jetty.JettyPamLoginModule requisite
        debug="true"
        service="sshd"
        supplementalRoles="admin"
        storePass="true";

    org.rundeck.jaas.jetty.JettyRolePropertyFileLoginModule required
        debug="true"
        useFirstPass="true"
        file="/etc/rundeck/realm.properties";

};
```

I now understand why every Unix system user I created would allow me to log into Rundeck, and also be an admin.

I, however, still do not understand why I cannot log in with a user I created in `realm.properties`.

I thought that the `JettyRolePropertyFileLoginModule` would allow us to create users in the `realm.properties` file, and then log into Rundeck with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `ReloadablePropertyFileLoginModule` module inside the `RDpropertyfilelogin`.

Following [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/authentication.html#pam), the `JettyRolePropertyFileLoginModule` isn't for authentication purposes.

> org.rundeck.jaas.jetty.JettyRolePropertyFileLoginModule **does not
> authenticate** and only uses authorization roles from a property file.
> Can be combined with previous modules.

So, to get it to work follow this config and restart the Rundeck service:

The `jaas-loginmodule.conf` file:

```java
RDpropertyfilelogin {
    org.rundeck.jaas.jetty.JettyPamLoginModule optional
        debug="true"
        service="sshd"
        supplementalRoles="user,readonly"
        storePass="true";

    org.rundeck.jaas.jetty.ReloadablePropertyFileLoginModule optional
        debug="true"
        useFirstPass="true"
        file="/etc/rundeck/realm.properties"
        storePass="true";

    org.rundeck.jaas.jetty.JettyRolePropertyFileLoginModule required
        debug="true"
        useFirstPass="true"
        file="/etc/rundeck/realm.properties";
};
```

The `realm.properties` file.

```
admin:admin,admin
bob: -,admin
```

The `bob` user (PAM) entry it's just to define the admin role for him.

Now, with the `JettyRolePropertyFileLoginModule` module you can add any user on the `realm.properties` file without restarting Rundeck keeping the PAM auth users too.

Tested on Rundeck 4.3.1 (Debian 9).

Comment: Okay so I have tried adding a user to realm.properties and restarting rundeck.
I already had an Access Control Policy created for the group I added that new user to.
I have not created a unix user for them.
I am unable to log in to rundeck with the user I "created" in that realm.properties. 
The user also does not show up when I use the rd CLI tool to list user info.

Comment: Could you share your `realm.properties` file content? The "list users" rd cli function works after the first login, so, if you're unable to log in with your new user you can't see the new user using `rdcli users list` command.

Comment: I have edited my question to contain the information you requested, more information for context, and info about what I have been investigating since.

Comment: Done, I updated my answer, I replicated your environment, and I found a solution (tested here!), thanks for the clarification, hope it helps!